# storyboard specific for iphone 4 when designing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

So I have been designing my app in storyboard for a few hours and realized upon testing that the storyboard windows are the size for the iphone 5. How do I make it so that they are only iphone 4 views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an icon at the bottom if the storyboard that looks like a long screen. Click it and it toggles the height