# Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes in Storyboards (3.5 and 4 inch screens)

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am trying to create a tic tac toe app that will work on both the 3.5 and 4 inch iPhones. However, I am not successful in finding out how to do this in a storyboard. I found the option when using XIB files, but cannot find the Simulated Metrics options when using storyboards. Is there any way to have the app automatically resize when using it on either screen size? Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [storyboard specific for iphone 4 when designing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220212/storyboard-specific-for-iphone-4-when-designing) Not an __exact__ duplicate, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Bottom right-hand corner in IB; in Xcode 4 it is labelled `Apply Retina 4 Form Factor` and toggles between this and `Apply Retina 3.5 Form Factor` to see your auto-layout in action.

Comment: The app will automatically change the size. And you can preview by following @capyJacks's answer

Comment: Use springs and struts, Autolayout, or size your views in code to support multiple screen sizes (adjust your views to the screen/window size).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there is a way to simulate the metrics in Storyboards.

**In Xcode 5:**

Once you open your storyboard, if you look in the bottom right corner, there are a set of buttons. The single button on the left will toggle between the two iPhone screen sizes, so you will be able to to make sure that your app looks good on both screens:

[image]

**In Xcode 6:**

Simply select the ViewController you wish to simulate by clicking on the top tab (with the three icons), select the Attributes inspector and specify your size under Simulated Metrics -> Size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is you can do this from the size and height tab in your right side however i'm not guaranteeing it will work if you enable rotation on the view. just anchor the view to one of the sides and enable auoresizeing.