# Proportional views constraints

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create a view controller with two views, one of them is actually a custom tableview, something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to add some kind of proportional constraints, so that in all devices and all orientations the upper view will be in same relation to the bottom view? (here it looks like 1:3 more or less).

Trying to do it without writing any code...

Thanks in advance,
Ox.

Comment: Yes, this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174980/creating-a-percentage-based-ios-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in IB. Select both views, and choose "Equal Heights" from the pin menu. Edit the constraint, and change the multiplier to what you want (like 3 or 0.33 depending on what order the views are in).