# How to make UiView respect percentage in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, uistoryboard

I have been struggling with this for days: I have a View Controller in storyboard which must contain four subviews filling the whole screen. Starting from y=0, I want them to represent 10%, 5%, 20% and 65% of the screen respectively on each iphone size. However, I can't find the constraints I need to do so.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Try this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174980/creating-a-percentage-based-ios-layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use AspectRatio constraint for this. Pick one item as containerView height and the other as your UIView height.