# Limit app to running only on 4 inch devices IOS

Tags: ios

I am creating an ios application for the iphone. I would like to make it run only on a 4 inch device (so the iphone 5 and the iPod touch 5). When I run it on one of these two, works fine. but when I run on the ipad, the X2 button appears, and the ipad simulates the old 3.5 inch display, not the 4 inch. Why?

Comment: Come again? The ipad simulates the 3.5 inch display? What? Your question is a little hard to understand.

Comment: you can design it for the ipad, then it will behave how you like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot choose an app to only be released for 4" devices, and you have no influence on what display the iPad simulates when it runs an iPhone only app. What you want is simply impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can not limit your app to run on a specific screen size or not, only specific iOS versions. There are ways to check the orientation and size of the screen and have it look a certain way, but the app will still run.

You should just design the app to look good on both the 3.5 and 4 inch screens. You can do that by [toggling the screen size button when creating in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132334/2535467) (if you use IB).

If you want to make your app able to run on both iPad and 3.5 and 4 inch iOS devices, you should make your app a "Universal" app.

But I understand what you mean by running it on the iPad simulator, and as @Scott said, the screen size displayed in the iPad simulator means nothing.

Instead of avoiding the problem (looks bad on 3.5") solve it (make it look good on both)!

Comment: oh I thought that I could say "available for ipod touch 5th gen, iphone 5 running iOS...", but if not I will have to design a 3.5 inch user interface as well. At least I know, thanks

Comment: @user2014474 Yeah, it shouldn't be hard to make it look good on both though, just use that button I showed you. Also make sure you check off an answer, whether Scott's, or mine.

Comment: i'll check @Scott. he was the first to answer :) but thanks anyway

Comment: No problemo @user2014474. I don't care who gets the points, I just hate question that get left open!