# how can I get and modify the display screen size in xcode4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3

I am developing an app, and I want it can be used on iPhone 4 and 5, as the iPhone 5 had changed its size to 4-inch, so I want my app can be supported 4-inch, but in Xcode4.3 there is no autolayout, because of this , I wonder if there is anyway to get the display screen size and change it to 4-inch, thank you very much!

Comment: make your app from code, not from IB

Comment: Why are you using xcode 4.3?

Comment: upgrade to 4.6 or higher & use this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18132334/2535467.

Comment: Even without auto layout, there still is autoresize. Autoresize is what was used before auto layout and does management of sizes and placement of views, though it's nowhere near as sophisticated as auto layout. Depending on your app it would probably work. I would, however, recommend updating Xcode if you can.

Comment: Finally, i update the Xcode to 4.5, and it is easy to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen size by using this code:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIViewController *ViewController;
[self loadall];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 5+");
    BOOL isUsingiPhone5 = YES;
}
else{
    NSLog(@"User is using an iPhone 4s-");
    BOOL isUsingiPhone5 = NO;
}
```

then you could move things accordingly, with `CGRect` heres an example of moving an ad banner view as a result of the screen size:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
CGRect bannerFrame = banner.frame;
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIViewController *ViewController;
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    //iPhone5+
    bannerFrame.origin.x = 0;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = 518;
    banner.frame = bannerFrame;
}
else{
    //iPhone4s-
}
NSLog(@"Showing ad, internet connection found.");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
else{
    [banner setAlpha:0];
}
```

Make sure to use `ViewController` as the `UIViewController` variable, even if your default view controller is named something like RootViewController.

Hope this helps. Feel free to comment if you have any questions!